# loading content into a div with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey All - I am having a bit of trouble with a jquery function.  I have a nav bar and I want when a user clicks on the nav bar to have the page load into a div (#content)

The code I have works for the first click, but when I try to click on another item it shows the loading image, but does not put the new content in the div (it leaves the old content).  Any thoughts?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $('.cat').live("click",function() {
        var section = $(this).attr("id");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../soccer/nav/" + section + ".php",

            beforeSend:  function() {
                $('div#content').hide();
                $('div#loading').show();
            },

            success: function(html){
                $('div#loading').hide();
                $("div#content").replacewith(html);
            }
        });     
        return false;
    });
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `.replacewith()` method. You are actually replacing the `#content` div with the new content.  Just use `.html()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `$("div#content")`.   You can just do `$("#content")`

`$("#content")` means find the node with the id "content".

Comment: Just want to add: Because ids are to be unique, according to the standard. (If your ids aren't unique -- which I've seen, unfortunately -- you're doing it wrong! :-)

Comment: Also, to clarify, `"div#content"` would still work, but it's unnecessary to include `div`, as you say. Adding `div` causes an additional wasted calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
$.post("../soccer/nav/" + section + ".php", null, function(data)
{
   $('#loading').hide();
   $("#content").html(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [jQuery.Load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) event to make use of ajax and html populating at the same time.